# Calling from wrong thread exception

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am trying to develop an application, that uses threads to implement slideshow. I am retrieving the image path from SQLite and displaying them on the ImageView. The problem, where I got struck is, I got confused and so I am unable to understand, from which thread I am calling images() method, where I am actually implementing the slideshow.

I got the Logcat as follows -

```
    09-03 13:47:00.248: E/AndroidRuntime(10642): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-151
09-03 13:47:00.248: E/AndroidRuntime(10642): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
09-03 13:47:00.248: E/AndroidRuntime(10642):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:5908)

09-03 13:47:00.248: E/AndroidRuntime(10642):    at com.example.fromstart.MainActivity.images(MainActivity.java:90)
09-03 13:47:00.248: E/AndroidRuntime(10642):    at com.example.fromstart.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:59)
09-03 13:47:00.248: E/AndroidRuntime(10642):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    ImageView jpgView;
    TextView tv;

    //adapter mDbAdapter;   
    adapter info = new adapter(this);
    String path; 
    Handler smHandler = new Handler() 
    {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        {
            TextView myTextView = 
            (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            myTextView.setText("Button Pressed");
        }
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        jpgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    { 
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);


        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() 
        {
                 public void run() 
                 {
                            images();
                 }
        };
        int delay = 1000; // delay for 1 sec.
        int period = 15000; // repeat every 4 sec.
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                smHandler.post(runnable);
            }
        }, delay, period);
        Thread mythread = new Thread(runnable);
        mythread.start();
        return true;
}
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        {             
            String string = "sample";
            TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            myTextView.setText(string);
        }
        public void images()
        {
            try
            {
                 for(int i=0;i<=20;i++)
                {
                     path = info.getpath();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
                jpgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                }
            }
            catch(NullPointerException er)
            {
                String ht=er.toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ht, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
         }
    }
```

I am a newbie to android, just now started working on Threads. If you find any mistakes in my code, please point out those and please suggest me, the right way to deal with this problem.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    // Create runnable for posting
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            images();
        }
    });
    int delay = 1000; // delay for 1 sec.
    int period = 15000; // repeat every 4 sec.
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            images();
        }
    }, delay, period);




}

public void images()
{
    try
    {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             path = info.getpath(); 
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        jpgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "4", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    catch(NullPointerException er) 
   {
            String ht=er.toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ht, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
     }

}
```

Comment: try using AsyncTask for all updates to the UI rather than the main thread..also the answer given below by @Raghunandan seems correct and addresses the same issue

Comment: @nki check my post use a handler instead of timer task

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot update/access ui from from a thread.

You have this

```
     public void run() 
     {
           images();
     }
```

And in images you have

```
    jpgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

You need to use `runOnUiThread` for updating ui.

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                      // do something
                    }
                });
```

TimerTask also runs on a different thread. So you have use a Handler for updati ui.

You can use a handler.

Edit:

```
Handler m_handler;
Runnable m_handlerTask ;  
m_handler = new Handler();   
m_handlerTask = new Runnable()
{
  @Override 
  public void run() { 

    // do something. call images() 
    m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, 1000);    

  }
  };
 m_handlerTask.run();
```

If you still wish to use a timer task use `runOnUiThread`

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                      images();
                    }
                }); 

        }
    }, delay, period);
```

Comment: Thank you @Raghunandan and @Photon for your reply. I have modified my code as per your suggestion. But, now I am getting the error, `RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`. What might might be the reason for this? Why is it necessary to have Looper.prepare() in the thread?

Comment: @nki as i said timer task runs on a different thread. so you cannot update ui from it. use a handler instead.

Comment: if I use postdelayed(), then there's no need of using runOnUiThread() right?

Comment: Thank you @Raghunandan, this code worked for me now. I used only postdelayed(), did not use runOnUiThread().

Comment: Every thing is okay now, but what should I do to call the function images() continuously? my updated code -                             ` m_handlertask = new Runnable(){

         @Override
         public void run() {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          
          for(int i=0;;i++){
           
           
          mHandler.postDelayed(m_handlertask,1000);
          images();}
         }
`

Comment: @nki call it inside a handler. check the handler in my post. every 1 second you call images

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36760/discussion-between-nki-and-raghunandan)

Answer (score 4):

To update UI from any other Thread you must use

```
runOnUiThread(<Runnable>);
```

which will update your UI.

**Example:**

```
runOnUiThread(
     new Runnable()
                 { 
                  // do something on UI thread Update UI
                 });
```